# java applet domain locking

Tags: java, security, jar, locking, dns

I need to be able to lock a java applet to a specific domain or range of domains. I know that it is possible to do this with flash .swf files [see article](http://www.ghostwire.com/blog/archives/as3-domain-locking-swfs/). I need to be able to do this with a java applet or jar. If anyone has any information on this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is really possible w/Flash.  If I want to view your Flash program from outside the approved domain, why couldn't I just run my own DNS and put myself in the approved domain.  The code is executed client-side right?

Comment: I'm not using flash.. I linked the article so as to give an example of what i'd like to do with java. I want control which url or urls the applet is served from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the web page which has the applet embedded:

[getDocumentBase()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29)

> Gets the URL of the document in which this applet is embedded. For example, suppose an
>   applet is contained within the document:
>
> ```
>     http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
> ```
>
> The document base is:
>
> ```
>     http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
> ```

If you want to control where the applet binaries (.jar) are hosted, I'm not sure how to do that. The applet classloader has that information, but I don't know if there's a way to access it from an applet.